# proving $\emptyset +Y=\emptyset Y = \emptyset$ where Y is the set consists of real numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am try to prove the equality of $\emptyset +Y=\emptyset Y = \emptyset$ where Y is the set consists of real numbers .But i dont know how to prove it.

Moreover,there is something i did not understand why is $\emptyset +Y=\emptyset$ ? Because, I think that let $ Y=\{1,2,3\} $ ,then $\emptyset +Y$ must be  $\emptyset +Y= \{1,2,3\} $ because empty set does not contain any element.

I am open for hints ,explanations and full proofs.

EDIT: $+$ means sumset, and $\emptyset Y$ means multiplication of empty set and Y

Comment: What do "$+$" and multiplication mean for sets (of real numbers)? Is addition just set union? Does your text have  definitions? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $A+B$ is the [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset), with definition:
$$A+B = \{a+b: a\in A, b \in B\}$$

it is easily seen that $\emptyset +Y = \emptyset$, since you cannot pick an element from $\emptyset$.

Below is a rigorous proof by contradiction.

---

Suppose on the contrary $\emptyset +Y \ne \emptyset$.

Let $x \in \emptyset +Y$. By definition there exists $a \in \emptyset$, $b\in Y$ such that $a + b = x$.

But $\exists a \in \emptyset$ is a falsehood. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Or even more directly and without any need to reduce to absurdity, by definition $\varnothing+X=+[\varnothing \times X]$, the image through the binary operation $+ \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of the cartesian product $\varnothing \times X$, which is empty since one of the factors is empty.

Comment: Proving your statement effectively reduces to this proof by contradiction. But yes, your statement is more intuitive.

Comment: You are right, ultimately proving that a cartesian product is empty given at least one empty factor conceals the reduction to absurdity you mentioned.